# Command to install .bin without user interruption in terminal

Tags: package-management

I'm writing a shell script to install `jira` in unattended mode. I've already done `chmod +x` to the file, but I'm stuck with the installation part. Please let me know where to mention this respose .varfile and how to create it.

Comment: What do you mean by "without user interruption"?

Comment: Do you mean like a windows answer file?

Comment: @edwinksl OP Probably means 'unattended install'

Answer (score 7):

[Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/installing-jira-on-linux-720411834.html#InstallingJIRAonLinux-PerforminganUnattendedInstallation) does suggest that JIRA has unattended installation mode.  Basically you will need to edit `response.varfile` and provide it as parameter to the installer, like so

```
atlassian-jira-X.Y.bin -q -varfile response.varfile
```

Note that `-q` and `-varfile` are flags to the installer, and `response.varfile` is the actual file that contains your settings. The actual binary in your case is `atlassian-jira-software-7.1.9-x32.bin`

For step by step instructions , follow the link above

Answer (score 6):

Considering you've already `chmod +x` the file

You could try reading https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/installing-jira-on-linux-720411834.html

See **Performing an Unattended Installation**
You'll see it requires a **varfile**

```
atlassian-jira-X.Y.bin -q -varfile response.varfile
```

Reference:
https://github.com/docker-atlassian/jira/blob/master/response.varfile